F# class in Azure isolated process function. No job functions found
I could not create an Azure isolated process function if I use F# class semantics, it works with the native F# function semantic. Could someone please take a look? Thank you!
The error is: No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions [...more...]
module Functions

open Domain
open Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

// this works, but could not use dependency registered in Host
[<Function("TimerTriggerFunction")>]
let TimeIntervalFunction ([<TimerTrigger("*/10 * * * * *")>] myTimer: TimerInfo) (context: FunctionContext) =
    let logger = context.GetLogger("functionlogger")
    logger.LogInformation("function is triggered!")


// I need dependency injection but this doesn't work
type public TimeIntervalFunctionClass() =

    [<Function("TimerTriggerFunctionInClass")>]
    member _.Run ([<TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")>] myTimer: TimerInfo) (context: FunctionContext) =
        let logger = context.GetLogger("classlogger")
        logger.LogInformation("timer trigger in class")
        


Can you share your local.settings.json and host.json?

@Pavan hi, the solution is I have to put the class under a namespace, not a module, because that will compile down to a nested class in IL, which possibly confuses Azure function

I found the solution. I have to put the class under a namespace, not a module, because that will compile down to a nested class in IL. Azure Function attribute possibly could not scan nested class.
